# MvvmCross navigation through multiple view models

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am developing an app for Android (later also iOS) using Xamarin and MvvmCross (currently 5.6.2). I am using the native UIs of both platforms (Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS).

The app has a hierarchial, folder like structure. Navigating into this structure and navigating back is working fine in the simple case.

In some cases though I need to navigate into this hierarchial structure from another top level view model. To support proper back navigation the navigation stack should change from i.e.

```
home -> vm1
```

to

```
home -> root -> folder -> folder -> vm2
```

Currently I call `await NavigationService.Close()` in `vm1`, work with the returned value in `home`, then do a series of calls to `await NavigationService.Navigate<>()` there to reach `vm2`.

The navigation (also back) is working fine, but during the transition to `vm2` the views of `home` etc. are briefly displayed. This is really distracting.

How can I navigate through multiple view models (and work with return values etc.), but not display the views except for the final one?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with MVVMCross since it [allows only to Navigate](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation) to a specific VM.
With the normal Xamarin.Forms navigation you could use:

```
Navigation.InsertPageBefore (page, before);
Navigation.RemovePage (page);
```

And modify your navigation stack, inserting or removing the pages you need.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)

Comment: He's saying that he uses native Xamarin not Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Ops, that's my bad